# Ajustar largura do listview para entrada dos dados do banco mysql vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, listview

Estou com um problema para ajustar a largura com listview em VB.net, onde os dados carregados do banco de dados não se ajusta a largura. Exemplo: Tem um registro do banco de dados que tem a largura de 250 caracteres e coloquei a instrução da seguinte forma:

```
If MTramo.Text = "Lobinho" Then
        mlv1.Items.Clear()

        Using con As MySqlConnection = GetConnection()
            Try
                con.Open()
                Dim sql As String = ("SELECT Controle, Objetivo FROM objetivos WHERE  Ramo LIKE 'Lobinho' AND Desenvolvimento = 'C-Carater' AND fase = 'a-Infância Média'")
                Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
                Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

                'CONFIGURA O LISTVIEW
                '=======================

                'Permite o usuário rearranjar as colunas
                mlv1.AllowColumnReorder = True

                'Exibe as caixas de marcação
                mlv1.CheckBoxes = True

                'Seleciona um item e subitem quando a seleção e feita
                mlv1.FullRowSelect = True

                'Cria as colunas com os nomes do cabeçalho usando os nomes dos campos da tabela
                With mlv1
                    .Columns.Add(dr.GetName(0), 80, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
                    .Columns.Add(dr.GetName(1), 435, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
                End With

                'Percorre a tabela e exibe todos os dados no listview
                While dr.Read
                    Dim texto As String = CType(dr.Item(0), String)
                    Dim lv As New ListViewItem(texto, 0)
                    lv.SubItems.Add(New ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(lv, CType(dr.Item(1), String)))
                    mlv1.Items.Add(lv)
                End While

                'Modo de visão
                mlv1.View = View.Details

                dr.Close()
```

Não estou conseguindo deixar a coluna "Objetivo" na largura necessária, que seria 435. Como posso fazer isso...se alguém puder me ajudar fico grato.

Segue a tela para exemplificar.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**===Código na View================**

```
Private Sub mlv1_ItemChecked(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckedEventArgs) Handles mlv1.ItemChecked
        For Each x As ListViewItem In Me.mlv1.Items
            If x.Checked = True Then
                If Me.mtxtOBJprg1.Text = Nothing And x.Text <> Me.mtxtOBJprg2.Text And x.Text <> Me.mtxtOBJprg3.Text Then 'verificar se TextBox1 esta vasia, se estiver add texto  ... 
                    Me.mtxtOBJprg1.Text = x.Text 'pegar o intem selecionado apenas o txt
                    Exit For
                ElseIf Me.mtxtOBJprg2.Text = Nothing And x.Text <> Me.mtxtOBJprg1.Text And x.Text <> Me.mtxtOBJprg3.Text Then 'verificar se TextBox2 esta vasia, se estiver add texto  ... 
                    Me.mtxtOBJprg2.Text = x.Text 'pegar o intem selecionado apenas o txt
                    Exit For
                ElseIf Me.mtxtOBJprg3.Text = Nothing And x.Text <> Me.mtxtOBJprg1.Text And x.Text <> Me.mtxtOBJprg2.Text Then 'verificar se TextBox3 esta vasia, se estiver add texto  ... 
                    Me.mtxtOBJprg3.Text = x.Text 'pegar o intem selecionado apenas o txt
                    Exit For
                End If
            Else
                If x.Text = Me.mtxtOBJprg1.Text Then
                    Me.mtxtOBJprg1.Clear()
                    Exit For
                ElseIf x.Text = Me.mtxtOBJprg2.Text Then
                    Me.mtxtOBJprg2.Clear()
                    Exit For
                ElseIf x.Text = Me.mtxtOBJprg3.Text Then
                    Me.mtxtOBJprg3.Clear()
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next x
    End Sub
```

Comment: posta o código HTML da sua view

Comment: Estou usando visual basic 2015 criando um programa em vb windows form e sou novato... não sei postar o código html da view. podem me ajudar.

Comment: Pensei que fosse HTML, para windows forms eu recomendo você utilizar as propriedades anchor e dock